# How to display Bitmap image in Dialog by copying it to another Bitmap Object?

Tags: android, bitmap, android-asynctask, dialog, imageview

I am trying to "inflate" or "enlarge" an image that I loaded from a URL into an ImageView. I want to then take the Bitmap that was loaded and store it into a Bitmap Object so that I can call an AlertDialog with another ImageView and set its ImageBitmap to the one I stored.

I used this AsyncTask class to do this:

```
class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
ImageView bmImage;

 public DownloadImageTask(ImageView bmImage) {
    this.bmImage = bmImage;
 }

 protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
    String urldisplay = urls[0];
    Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
    try {
        InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
        mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return mIcon11;
 }

 protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
    bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
 }
}
```

Here is the method in my Activity that I call in onCreate method:

```
public void loadUI() throws IOException {
    prefs = getSharedPreferences(SELECTED_PREFS, MODE_PRIVATE);

    lblEntryNumber = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblCEntryNumber);
    lblEntryNumber.setText(cosplayerPrefs.getString(KEY_ENTRY_NUMBER, null));

    ImageView imgReference = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgReference);

    if (prefs.getString(KEY_REFERENCE_LINK, null).startsWith("http")){
        bImage = new DownloadImageTask((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgReference)).execute(cosplayerPrefs.getString(KEY_REFERENCE_LINK, null)).get();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(ContestantActivity.this, "Invalid URL for Image...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    imgReference.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        Bitmap clone = bImage;
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ContestantActivity.this);
            ImageView imgRefInflated = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgRefInflated);
            imgRefInflated.setImageBitmap(clone);

            builder.setNegativeButton("Close", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });

            AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_layout);
            dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

            dialog.show();
        }
    });
```

When I run this, the app runs into some errors in `imgRefInflated.setImageBitmap(clone);` and I have no clue why. Does anybody have a suggestion about what I could do to resolve this?

**EDIT:** It would seem that the ImageView `imgRefInflated` is returning null, but I don't understand why.

Comment: what are the errors exactly?

Comment: It seems to be a NullPointerException on the line `imgRefInflated.setImageBitmap(clone);` , which I'm having difficulty understanding why the object is null, but when I've debugged I was able to see that `clone` had a bitmap image inside of it.

Comment: It would seem that `imgRefInflated` is returning a null object, so it cannot assign the bitmap image to `imgRefInflated`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I eventually found the answer. The problem was that I needed to inflate and store the dialog_layout.xml in a seperate view and then declare my ImageView variable and set the View to my dialog. [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) works great with loading the image. Here is my final result code.

```
imgReference.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        //Bitmap clone = bImage;
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            View view = View.inflate(ContestantActivity.this, R.layout.dialog_layout, null);
            ImageView imgRefInflated = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imgRefInflated);
            Picasso.with(ContestantActivity.this).load(sURL).into(imgRefInflated);

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ContestantActivity.this);

            builder.setNegativeButton("Close", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });

            AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
            dialog.setView(view);
            dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            dialog.show();
        }
    });
```

I hope someone else finds this useful.

Answer (score 1):

A single line does everything for you, which uses [Picasso library](http://square.github.io/picasso/):

```
Picasso.with(this).load(urldisplay).into(imgRefInflated );
```

where this refers to a context (e.g. an activity).

Comment: I have added Picasso to my project, and I replaced the line `imgRefInflated.setImageBitmap(clone);` with `Picasso.with(ContestantActivity.this).load(sURL).into(imgRefInflated);` but it seems to give an IllegalArgumentExxception saying that the "Target cannot be null"
Perhaps I should `setContentView` for the dialog first and then call Picasso?